# PHP Update Prepared Statement Issue

Tags: php, html, sql

Here is the updated code for anyone looking to update their database. Thank you everyone for all your help.

```
<?php
  try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, 
 $password);
// set the PDO error mode to exception
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// prepare sql and bind parameters
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE test SET title=:title WHERE id=:id");
$stmt->bindParam(':title', $title);  
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);

// Update a row
$title = $_POST['title'];
$id = $_POST['id'];
$stmt->execute();
echo "Row updated"; 
echo "<br />";
echo "<strong>$title</strong> and <strong>$id</strong>";
 }
 catch(PDOException $e) {
echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
 }
$conn = null;
?>
```

Comment: Are you using `mysqli` or `PDO`? because you're making a connection with `mysqli` but you're using `PDO` statements. It looks like you pasted some `PDO` code into the middle of some `mysqli` code.

Comment: Looks like you are mixing pdo and mysqli together.  You are using parameters like PDO using a Mysqli connection.

Comment: I am using mysqli. I didn't paste it. I was using a php mysql reference book. So I need to update my connection section?

Comment: I have updated my connection but still no luck. - `try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", 
    $username,
        $password);
// set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still have a bit of a mix of PDO and MySQLi although only in your call to `bindParam` now, which you are calling as if it was `MySQLi::bind_param`. Also in your last edit the query string got messed up with the addition of `Values=?` I'm not sure why you did that? Anyway, this should do what you want:

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    // prepare sql and bind parameters
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE test SET title=:title WHERE id=:id");
    $stmt->bindParam(':title', $title);  
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);

    // Update a row
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $stmt->execute();
    echo "Row updated";
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
```

Comment: It is still not updating the database but at least I am not getting an error message any longer. Thanks for your help I really appreciate it.

Comment: Hi @Reed, you shouldn't mark accepted if your problem isn't solved. Perhaps the problem is with the value of `$id`? Have you tried just running the query with the raw values (e.g. `UPDATE test SET title='x' WHERE id=1`) in something like phpMyAdmin or MySQL workbench?

Comment: No, I figured it out. All we were missing was `$id = $_POST['id'];` under Update a row. Once I put that there it updated the database. Your code got me to this point, so thank you.

Comment: Hi, question do you know why I would be getting `â€‹` before my echo? I have tried a few things and nothing. Sorry to bother you again. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi @Reed, if you mean before the "Row Updated", there's nothing in the code I posted that would produce that. None of the PDO functions will produce any output. Sorry...

Answer (score 1):

Use bind_param() :

```
<?php
   $statement = $conn->prepare("UPDATE test SET title= ? WHERE id= ?");
   $statement->bind_param('si', $title,$id);
   $statement->execute();
   if ($statement->affected_rows >0) {
      echo "Record updated successfully";
   } else {
      echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
   }
   $statement->close();
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. So with your code, I receive the following error --  "Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::prepared() in /test/myupdate.php on line 16" -- this is what is on line 16 - $statement = $conn->prepared("UPDATE test SET title= ? WHERE id= ?");

Comment: @Reed change 'prepared' to 'prepare'

Comment: I have updated the code above in my question to what I have now based on feedback. I am just getting a blank page. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
use this.hope it will help you.
<?php
$statement = $conn->prepare("UPDATE myTable SET name = ? WHERE id = ?");
$statement->bind_param("si", $_POST['title'],$id);
$statement->execute();
$statement->close();
?>
```

Comment: Can you explain your code such that others can learn from it?